# How to spawn a 'boss' after a certain amount of time has passed and then kill that 'boss'?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I only have basic ability with Unity and cannot figure out the answer to what looks like a simple question. I have three enemies in my level, and would like to spawn a 'boss' once they're defeated. Here is my original spawn code so far:

```
//here are the 3 enemys we want to spawn (the orb, asteroid, and ship)
var enemy1:GameObject;
var enemy2:GameObject;
var enemy3:GameObject;

//here is the minimum and maximum height we want them to spawn. it can be changed in the inspector
var maxHeight:float = 6.0;
var minHeight:float = -6.0;

//here are private variables we use for the spawner
private var counter:float = 0.0;
private var player:GameObject;
private var randomChoice:int;
private var spawnRate:float = 2.0;

function Update () {
    //counter counts based on time here so the spawner can spawn based on time
    counter += Time.deltaTime;

    //here we make the spawner slowly spawn faster until it is spawning 3 a second.
    if(spawnRate > 0.33){
        spawnRate -= Time.deltaTime/80;
    }

    //if the counter is higher than the spawnrate number, it'll spawn an object
    if(counter > spawnRate){
        //before one is spawned we have to decide at random which one to spawn
        randomChoice = Random.Range(1,6);

        //asteroids take up 3 out of the 5 possible spawns, making it spawn the most often
        if(randomChoice >= 1 && randomChoice <= 3){
            Instantiate(enemy1, Vector3(transform.position.x,0,Random.Range(minHeight,maxHeight)), Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,0));
        }

        //if the random number ends up being 4, it'll spawn the orb, set as enemy2
        if(randomChoice == 4){
            Instantiate(enemy2, Vector3(transform.position.x,0,Random.Range(minHeight/3,maxHeight/3)), Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,0));
        }

        //if the random number ends up being 5, it'll spawn the ship, set as enemy3
        if(randomChoice == 5){
            Instantiate(enemy3, Vector3(transform.position.x,0,Random.Range(minHeight,maxHeight)), Quaternion.Euler(-90,90,0));
        }

        counter = 0.0;
    }

}
```

The code I experimented with got really messed up and disorganized. This script spawns all my enemies and is attached to my level scene. Please point me in the right directions as to how to add the boss part to the script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boss should spawn the moment all three enemies all defeated, is that right?
In that case, you already have the condition for when the boss will spawn.

Make a variable like `private var defeatedEnemies:int = 0;` and increment it the moment an enemy dies.

Then you just need to add that condition in your `update()` function:

```
if (defeatedEnemies == 3){
   // spawn the boss
}
```

Comment: just to clarify do i need to make a public variable for my boss prefab?

Comment: the boss is basically the same as normal enemies, the difference is only it spawns when all the normal ones die. So, the prefab should also be similar to `var enemy3:GameObject;`.
`var boss:GameObject;` for example.

Comment: ok so apart from adding the boss game object, there is nothing else to change or add?

Comment: Well apart from that, you also need to create a variable that represents the number of defeated enemies, increment it each time an enemy dies and add a condition for when the boss will spawn (just like my answer). Instantiate the boss the same way you instantiate enemies, with the boss game object. Dont forget to insert the boss prefab into your boss game object from the inspector.

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting my answer so your question doesn't leave unanswered. :)